# How to get the value with the smaller absolute value from a panda Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

How can I get the value with the smaller absolute value from a panda Series?

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_min_absvalue(values):
    ¿?

lst = [-2.1,2.2,-1.5]

ser = pd.Series(lst)
min_absvalue = get_min_absvalue(ser)
#min_absvalue must be -1.5 here
```

Comment: Using pandas methods `ser.loc[ser.abs().idxmin()]` should do it @MrGeek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `min` with `abs` as a key function:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_min_absvalue(values):
    return min(values, key = abs)

lst = [-2.1, 2.2, -1.5]

ser = pd.Series(lst)
min_absvalue = get_min_absvalue(ser)

print(min_absvalue)
```

Output:

```
-1.5
```